# Check if the command author has a specific role from a list of role IDs

Tags: python, bots, discord

Currently, I'm only able to check the command author for a specific role ID as a string variable, but I can't get it to check a list if any of the IDs in the list match an ID of a role assigned to them. I've tried numerous things for a few days now, but It always either lets through every ID or none.

This is the current code for checking a single variable:

```
if (allowed_role_id in [roles.id for roles in ctx.message.author.roles]): 
    # TODO here
else:
    # Other TODO here
```

I want It to check from a list like this:

```
listOfAllowedRoles = ['11111111111111111', '22222222222222222', '3333333333333333']
```

And If the command author has a role of which ID matches an ID from the list above to execute the TODO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](https://www.techbeamers.com/program-python-list-contains-elements/#any-method) to check if a list contains at least one element of the other list:

```
# Whatever role ID
listOfAllowedRoles = [213183812831, 1238183283183813 ]

# Wont work if message is not in a guild
rolesUserHas = message.author.roles

# Or some other better way to get the list of IDs of roles the user has.
rolesIDuserHas = []
for role in rolesUserHas:
  rolesIDuserHas.append(role.id)

if any(item in listOfAllowedRoles for item in rolesIDuserHas):
  # User has at least one of the roles
else:
  #user do not have any of the roles.
```

#### Edit

Basically, `listOfAllowedRoles` are the *list* of roles which you... want to check against, aka the roles that the user needs (at least the IDs of it).

Then first, we get the roles that the user currently has by doing `message.author.roles`, this returns a *list* of roles which we store it in `rolesUserHas`.
However, we still cant compare both lists, since one of is a list of IDs (numbers), and the other is a list of roles (not numbers, aka you cant compare a number against a non-number)

So what I did was to "convert" the list of roles into a list of role-IDs that the user has, which is stored into `rolesIDuserhas`
(How I "converted" it was by simply creating a new list, and adding all the IDs of each role into the list)

So now we got a list of IDs (`listOfAllowedRoles`, numbers) to compare against another list of IDs (`rolesIDuserhas`, numbers). But all we want is to check if the user has at least *any* of the roles in that first list
The [`any()`](https://www.techbeamers.com/program-python-list-contains-elements/#any-method) function in python does exactly what we want.

Hence, `any(item in listOfAllowedRoles for item in rolesIDuserHas)` will return true if the user has at least one of the roles in the list of `listOfAllowedRoles`.

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense to me, sorry. Besides the stand-alone `roleToCheck` and `roleUserHas`, which I can't comprehend why, the `rolesIDuserHas.add(role.id)` throws me an error "_AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add'_". Just to clarify - I don't have the sole role ID I want to check. I have many in a list that all need to be checked and if even one matches it needs to return True.

Comment: @SpicySouce Sorry, I fixed it. It was `append`, not `add`. Finally, I edited my answer to added explanation of my codes, and made my codes a little bit more understandable. And yes, I got your clarification and the code does solve it.

Comment: From your explanation, I did get a better understanding and confirmed some of my thoughts, but the question still stands - Why are there `roleToCheck` and `roleUserHas`. It even throws me "_NameError: name 'roleToCheck' is not defined_" and as I see it `roleUserHas` is defined then and there and is unused. Perhaps you meant _role_**s**_UserHas_? Could you please provide the explanation for those two? Thanks

Comment: @SpicySouce Fixed, it. Replace those with `item`. Sorry for the inconvenience, since I had no tools to test this while answer this question (and I had confused that `item` was kind of a variable naming like a loop)